# tensorflow MDA custom loss and ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I would like to use the MDA (mean direction accuracy) as a custom loss function for a tensorflow neural network.

I am trying to implement this as described in here:
[Custom Mean Directional Accuracy loss function in Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46876213/custom-mean-directional-accuracy-loss-function-in-keras)

```py
def mda(y_true, y_pred):
    s = K.equal(K.sign(y_true[1:] - y_true[:-1]),
                 K.sign(y_pred[1:] - y_pred[:-1]))
    return K.mean(K.cast(s, K.floatx()))
```

The network works fine but when I try to fit my data I am getting this error:

```
 ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable
```

I think that this is because I am loosing the gradient info from my pred tensor but I don't know how can implement this.... or if this makes any sense at all.... Finally I want to predict is if some numeric series is going up or down, that is why this function made sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that with `K.equal` and `K.cast`, you change numbers into bools. As a result, no gradient can be calculated.

You could replace them with a calculation; using the fact that when two numbers are equal, their difference is zero, and that since `sign` returns only [-1, 0, 1], the absolute difference can only be 0, 1 or 2:

```
def mda(y_true, y_pred):
    d = K.abs(K.sign(y_true[1:] - y_true[:-1]) - (K.sign(y_pred[1:] - y_pred[:-1])))
    s = (1. - d) * (d - 1.) * (d - 2.) / 2.
return K.mean(s)
```

`s` is equal `1` when your `K.equal` is true, and `0` otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Reda and AndrzeO for your answers my question. As AndrzejO mention, equals transform the data to boolean so no gradient there.

I implemented this other solution as an alternative to AndrzejO solution:

```py
def mda_custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    res = tf.math.sign(y_true[1:] - y_true[:-1]) - tf.math.sign(y_pred[1:] - y_pred[:-1])
    s = tf.math.abs(tf.math.sign(res))
    return 1 - tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.math.sign(s))
```